# How does this snippet of Makefile code work? (For using more than 1 compiler)

Tags: visual-c++, makefile, intel

So I've got this piece of code:

```
SOURCEFILE.$(OBJ_SUFFIX): SOURCEFILE.cpp $(GLOBAL_DEPS)
  $(REPORT_BUILD)
  @$(MAKE_DEPS_AUTO_CXX)
$(ELOG) $(CCC:icl=cl) $(OUTOPTION)$@ -c $(COMPILE_CXXFLAGS:O3=O2) $(COMPILE_CXXFLAGS:arch:SSE3=arch:SSE2) $(_VPATH_SRCS)
```

So I see that it compiles the specific file with VC as opposed to ICL, and changes some of the flags to be VC compatible. The thing is I can't find any Makefile documentation for how to switch compilers mid-compile. I'm not exactly sure what to be searching for let a lone being able to find documentation for it.

Also, could this be used just for header files? At the moment I'm encountering an error where ICL won't compile a header file, but VC will.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that fourth line a command in the rule? It doesn't seem to begin with a TAB, but it also doesn't look like Make syntax. What is `ELOG`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using [string substitution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsd42ets.aspx) to hack in 'cl' in place of the Intel compiler ('icl').

Actions in a makefile are typically defined based on the extension of the file to process; for example, that how the Resource Compiler gets involved for .rc files. But in this case it looks like we are singling out a specific file, and then modifying the variables.

Since a .h file isn't 'compiled' as a separate entity, you won't be able to use a different compiler for processing a specific header (compiler 1 will have no way of passing that data to compiler 2). Your best option is to either contact the compiler manufacturer to see if they have a compatible version of the header or to hand modify the file so that it builds with the toolset you are using.

Comment: I was just wondering, is it possible to use a Makefile to have a whole directory compiled by a separate compiler?